# ORA-01780: string literal required in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

DIRECT PROJECTS IN SECTION HAVE:

```
create directory hr_imp_dir as ‘/u02/oradata/hr_imp_dir/’ ;
```

For example: EXPORT 2 EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS tables using the datapump tool:

```
expdp hr/hr@orcl tables=EMPLOYEES,DEPARTMENTS directory=hr_imp_dir 
dumpfile =EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expEMP_DEPT.log
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Oracle complains about those "fancy" single quotes you used. If your editor is e.g. Microsoft Word or Wordpad or something like this, abandon it and use pure text editor (such as Notepad or Notepad++ or similar). Because, these quotes aren't *recognized*.

```
No : create directory hr_imp_dir as ‘/u02/oradata/hr_imp_dir/’ ;

Yes: create directory hr_imp_dir as '/u02/oradata/hr_imp_dir/' ;
```

There's no evidence that - once you created directory - you granted required privileges to user(s) who will be using it, so - maybe you're missing

```
grant read, write on directory hr_imp to hr;
```

---

Furthermore, Export Data Pump is an **operating system level** utility. You have to run it from its command prompt, not from SQL*Plus. For example:

```
No       : SQL> expdp hr/hr@orcl ...

Yes      : C:\> expdp hr/hr@orcl

Also yes : SQL> $expdp hr/hr@orcl ...     --> precede OS command with $ while in SQL*Plus
```